# When are includes expanded in Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am starting to learn make and I came across making the compiler regenerate the object files prerequisites. I got it working in a dummy project but I don't quite understand when does make expand the include statements as in my case they contain the rules for making the object files.

```
  1 CC=cc 
  2 CFLAGS=-Wall -MM
  3 
  4 CFILES=add.c mul.c  
  5 
  6 all:libmath.a 
  7 
  8 libmath.a:add.o mul.o
  9         ar -cvq libmath.a $^
 10 
 11 include $(CFILES:.c=.d)
 12                        
 13 %.d:%.c 
 14         set -e; rm -f $@; \
 15         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
 16         sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
 17         rm -f $@.$$$$
```

so my question is simply when does make reads/expands these include statements ? Is there a "preprocessor" for example ? or make reads it when it reaches this statement ?

Also, if there is no "preprocessor" that expands these statements before the all target starts, what happens when make starts looking for the rules of the .o files and can't find them ?

Comment: In general, Make "preprocesses" (expands functions/variables in) the whole makefile before executing it. Except for recipe bodies, which are expanded when they're executed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This clears up my doubts.

Comment: If your `include` statement calls for files that don't exist, Make will try to rebuild them -- and include them -- before working on any other targets.

Comment: so in my case if there is no .d files make will search for its rule and build it ?

Comment: Yes.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html  However this is way of managing dependency files is considered obsolete and better ways exist.  See http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ for example